# Print When Expression Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports

Is the following Print When Expression invaild:

```
29 <= $F{selfawarenesscore} <= 45
```

I get the following error in *JasperReports Server*

```
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSExceptionWrapper: 
Errors were encountered when compiling report expressions class file:
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
calculator_subreport2_EmotionalSelfAwareness40QI41_1370531739954_546871: 233: 
unexpected token: <= @ line 233, column 83. 1 error
```

I want to print a text field when *$F{selfawarenesscore}* is the above mentioned range.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
 $F{selfawarenessscore} >= 29 && $F{selfawarenessscore} <= 45
```